# Does the OP get notified when I undelete my answer?

Tags: support, answers, notifications

I just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709735/5133585).

After I posted it I realised that actually I was wrong, so I went and deleted it.

After some time, I came up with a correct answer, so I edited the deleted answer and then undeleted it, as you can see from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45709735/revisions).

Does the OP get notified when I undelete my answer? I am asking this because the OP might see the notification when the answer was posted and dismissed it since the answer was wrong. But now the answer has been edited and undeleted, if the OP does not get notified by this, I need to tell him/her in a comment or something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OP does not receive any notification when you undelete your answer.

Comment: I'd deleted this answer, then I've updated, then I've undeleted this answer.

Comment: I didn't get a notification! I guess it's QED then.

Comment: @Sweeper To be honest I've expected such behaviour... It's just feels like it works exactly in this way. But, I think it would be helpful to have notification in this case...

Comment: when undeleting, make sure you leave a comment for the OP so notification occurs (note: same goes for the edits)

Comment: AFAIK, when you undelete an answer, it goes active.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, but you have to leave comment explicitly, but it would be nice to have notice implicitly, without unnecessary comment because it looks like spam...

Comment: @Braiam Yes, but OP won't know about it.